# SignalR run with Mono and apache: HTTP 500 error (in SignalR code)

Tags: c#, .net, apache, mono, signalr

I've been running SignalR on mono with both self-hosting on localhost and on IIS. 
But self-hosting with mono on a server didn't work yet

**The full error I get on the webpage is:**

System.InvalidOperationException
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

```
Description:` HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.
Exception stack trace:
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.AsyncCallback cb, System.Object extradata) <0x404788f0 + 0x0074b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<RunHooks>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () <0x404715e0 + 0x00367> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () <0x40468000 + 0x01a65> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () <0x40465950 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0
```

**In the Apache error log:**

```
Cannot access a closed Stream.
  at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) <0x4006e720 + 0x0008b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write (Int32 value) <0x4006e660 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoRequest.IsConnected () <0x40540670 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.Apache.ModMonoWorker.IsConnected () <0x40540640 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorkerRequest.IsClientConnected () <0x405405b0 + 0x00030> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.get_IsClientConnected () <0x40540570 + 0x0002a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.get_IsClientConnected () <0x40540540 + 0x0001b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CheckIsClientConnected (System.Object obj) <0x40540490 + 0x00051> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.Timer+Scheduler.TimerCB (System.Object o) <0x4053daf0 + 0x001a7> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x403d3c60 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x403d09b0 + 0x0021a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x403d0980 + 0x00010> in <filename unknown>:0
```

#### My code looks just fine, my program.cs contains:

```
class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://*:80";
        using (Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to do, should I look to change something in my code to let it work with mono?

Comment: Do you really need SignalR and Mono? The ASP.NET team started working on the SignalR Core, which will work across Windows, Linux and OS X, inside ASP.NET Core.

Comment: It's not clear if this is SignalR specific or broader. If you look at stack traces you posted neither has SignalR frames. If you send a request to negotiate ({server}/signalr/negotiate) do you get any response?

Comment: @Pawel When the negotiating starts I get an 500 error with explanation: Error: No transport could be initialized successfully. Try specifying a different transport or none at all for auto initialization.(…) It must has something to do with Mono I guess..

Comment: @radu-matei On the roadmap it states that there won't be SignalR until ASP.Net Core 1.2

Comment: If the server doesn't work the client won't be able to connect. I think the problem here is not with SignalR per se but with the web application not working for some reason not related to SignalR. btw. The Core version of SignalR-Server (http://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) is now in a working state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use SignalR Core, problem solved! :)